# PropertyGrid does not work for picking a color

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid, color-picker

I have a class that I am viewing with a property grid with the following property:

```
private Color _borderColor = Color.Black;
[Browsable(true)]
[Category("Appearance")]
[DisplayName("Border Color")]
[Description("The color of the border.")]
[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black")]
public virtual Color BorderColor
{
    get
    {
        return _borderColor;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_borderColor != value)
        {
            _borderColor = value;

            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

I am having various intermittent problems changing this property using the property grid.

Initially, I am able to open the drop-down popup.  But when I pick a color it doesn't change the property.  When debugging, it does not even call the "set" accessor.  At this point, even if I type in the name of the color and press Enter, it doesn't change.

If I deselect the object (which sets the property grid's selecteditem to null), then re-select the object, I am then able to change the color by typing in its name.  But the popup still does not work.

Sometimes it bugs out and the popup won't even open when you click the dropdown arrow.

**EDIT:**

It's specifically a problem with the popup.  If I don't use the popup, I don't get any glitches.  Opening the popup basically suspends the change being committed (sending a PropertyChanged event) until the entire control loses focus.  So once I click on another window or another focusable control, the property grid updates the change.

The question is: why does double clicking or pressing enter cause a change commit, but clicking an item in the popup doesn't?

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Your code worked for me as posted.

Comment: If I copy my PropertyGrid to a different form in a blank project, it seems to work fine.  If I find all references in my code to this property grid, I only have a single line that references it which sets the SelectedObjects to my object(s).

Comment: The only difference is the control tree structure the PropertyGrid is in.  It's inside a SplitContainer, inside another SplitContainer, inside a Panel, inside a Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what is causing the issue.  I have set the window style WS_EX_COMPOSITED on one of the property grid's parents.  Disabling this style results in the PropertyGrid functioning normally again.

Unfortunately I need this style to reduce flickering in my application.  So I will most likely have to use something other than a PropertyGrid to change my object's properties.

Comment: Did you solve that problem? I'm suffering the same issue as you.

Comment: Yes, disabling WS_EX_COMPOSITED fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but That's not enough for me... I'll have to try something else... :(